# Handle Firebase topics notification on Android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send push notifications throught FCM services.
In my MainActivity I write this code:

```
   mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                // checking for type intent filter
                if (intent.getAction().equals(Config.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE)) {
                    // gcm successfully registered
                    // now subscribe to `global` topic to receive app wide notifications
                    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(Config.TOPIC_GLOBAL);

                    displayFirebaseRegId();

                } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION)) {
                    // new push notification is received

                    String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Push notification: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }
        };
```

In order to subscribe user to a topic.

From backend I make a call to FCM service at this link : https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

in which I pass this JSON:

```
{  
   "to":"/topics/global",
   "data":{  
      "title":"test",
      "is_background":false,
      "message":"testmessage",
      "image":"",
      "payload":{  
         "team":"Test",
         "score":"5.6"
      },
      "timestamp":"2017-05-23 11:55:35"
   }
}
```

and I get this response:

```
{\"message_id\":8863205901902209389}
```

But my device doesn't show any notifaction, exept if I use Firebase console with "user segment" or "single device" . Also in Firebase console doesn't works "topic" way.

Thank you in advance for any response.

Comment: Is that the full JSON String you are sending? Where is the "to":"/topics/topicName" property? Shouldn't you specify to which topic you wish send the message?

Comment: Hi Slaiv206. Is that the complete payload you're using? I'm not seeing the `to` parameter.

Comment: I edited the question , anyway I specified the topic but it is not working

Comment: What do you expect this payload to do? It doesn't contain a "notification" dictionary, so nothing will be automatically displayed by Android. You would have to process the "data" dictionary yourself.

Comment: When sending `data`-only message payloads, you should handle the payload yourself. See [Handling Messages in Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive).

Comment: Is the "global" topic showing up in your Firebase Notifications Console?

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of FCM messages.

1. Notification Messages
2. Data Messages

On the client side, Notification messages are handled by FCM and automatically displayed in the notification window. If you are using Data Messages, your app needs to handle the received message and create a notification.

The sample payload in your question is a data message and hence it is not displayed in notification (I assume you didn't do any handling). The notifications sent via FCM console are always notification messages and hence those are automatically displayed.

Refer to [this FCM page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options) for more details on this.

Comment: You mentioned that you receive user segment and single device messages, so I wonder if the code under `if (intent.getAction().equals(Config.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE))` is even getting executed. Maybe you are not subscribing to the topics at all. Did you verify that?